# No matching factory method for IOUtils static method

Tags: java, spring

```
<bean id="testMessage"
    class="org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils" factory-method="toString" >
    <constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="classpath:data/exampleMessage.xml" />
</bean>
```

Anyone know why I would be getting this error when calling this static toString method from Apache IOUtils in Spring?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
with name 'testMessage' defined in class path resource [data.xml]: No    
matching factory method found: factory method 'toString'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is valid to pass in parameters to a static factory method as of the Spring documentation chapter [3.3.1.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/beans.html#beans-some-examples):

> As you can see, the constructor arguments specified in the bean definition will be used to pass in as arguments to the constructor of the ExampleBean.

I think the value `classpath:data/exampleMessage.xml` is not an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) but an [InputStreamSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html) which is not an `InputStream` as of the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your requirement in Java Config using the following code (assuming that your are using Spring 3+):

```
@Bean
public String testMessage() {
   final Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("data/exampleMessage.xml");
   return IOUtils.toString(resource.getInputStream());
}
```